# How to run startActivity from outside of the main activity

Tags: java, android, start-activity

I have a `MainActivity` class which has a `NotificationsListener` (seperate class). When a notification appears, it calls my `gethtml` class. They both extend `Activity` but the `startActivity` in my `gethtml` class doesn't work... (If I copy and test this code in my `MainActivity`, it works fine)... Anyone have an idea why it isn't working?

This is the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.kpbird.nlsexample.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_EXAMPLE");
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NLService.class));
    Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
    startActivity(intent);        

    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

This is the notification listener:

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.kpbird.nlsexample.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE_EXAMPLE");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {   
    new Thread(new Runnable() {             
            public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            int cangethtml = 1;
                try{
                    if(cangethtml==1){
                        cangethtml = 0; //only runs once
                        new html();
                    }
                }finally{Looper.loop();}  
            }; 
        }).start();    
    }

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {}
}
```

This is the final class which doesn't open the website through the `startActivity`:

```
public class html extends Activity{
public html()  {
    try {
                Intent i2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                i2.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
                i2.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                i2.setData(Uri.parse("https://wwww.google.com"));
                startActivity(i2);

    }   finally{}
}
}
```

Comment: OK im at work right now, i will post everything later.. sorry

Comment: I don't think the html needs an activity.. If I add a System.out.println("hello"); it works..

Answer (score 0):

You need the context of the Activity. `startActivity` will be called in the context of `Activity`.

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Context

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the developer's forum:

You should write

```
Context.startActivity(i2);
```

instead of

```
startActivity(i2);
```

Plus, make sure you don't forget to have a corresponding `<activity>` declaration in your package's `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For instance:
Check in `AndroidManifest.xml` for all the classes defined by you. You have:

```
<activity android:name="packageName.className"/>
```

If your `html` class is not defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can not access the methods and layouts defined in it.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what to add to the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: For your error stated: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Context; Declare your NLService class as 'public static class NLService extends NotificationListenerService'